# How to prevent removing error pictures in Cypress?

Tags: automation

I want to prevent removing screenshots in Cypress. Each time the previous one is getting removed.

How can I prevent that in Cypress?

Because I want to keep all screenshots.

```
/Users/mac/cypress/cypress/screenshots
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cypress.json

Set "trashAssetsBeforeRuns": false

Comment: Is it with curly braces right? Trying now.

Comment: Yes @FiratYılmaz 

{
  "trashAssetsBeforeRuns": false
}